# Transferring files from localhost to Bluehost

Tags: php, mysql, xampp, bluehost

I have all the PHP files and mysql database created on localhost through XAMPP. I have an account on Bluehost. Now I want to launch my website. So where to transfer the PHP files and where to transfer the mysql files on Bluehost? I know I can do it through FTP but I don't know where to upload these files to get the website running?

Apart from that I have one more doubt. Suppose I create a database directly on web server using phpmyadmin facility provided by Bluehost and try to link my php file kept on local host to that database what's the procedure?

Answer (score 2):

You upload your files to the folder your domain is setup for, if you are using your main domain setup on bluehost (you can have multiple domains on same account, but they use different subdirectories of public_html) just put the files in public_html

As for the database you export your database on localhost (mysqldump or export feature of phpmysqladmin or whatever you use) and import it using the phpmysqlamdin import feature

and if by "link my php file kept on local host " you mean how do you change the php files to connect to the bluehost database you just change the mysql connections to use localhost, and the username and password of the database you setup on bluehost.

You can setup databases using bluehosts database wizard, it will walk you through making a database and setting up a user, those will be the database name, username and password you will need for the mysql connections.